# loading as2 in as3 from different domain

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to load swf like this :

```
var _mcl:Loader= new Loader();
var loader_context:LoaderContext= new LoaderContext();
loader_context.securityDomain= SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
_mcl.load(new URLRequest(p_url), loader_context);
_mcl.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadImageComplete);
_mcl.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onLoadImageError);
_mcl.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onLoadImageError);
```

but the problem is that some of the swf are in AS2 and their script don't excute (a simple stop() on the last frame is not executed and the movie loops)

If I remove
    loader_context.securityDomain= SecurityDomain.currentDomain;
it works, the AS2 files scripts are executed but flash throws a security error for the swf that come from a different domain

So I'm wondering if there is a way in an AS3 file to load AS2 swf from another domain ?

thanks

Comment: So without SecurityDomain it throws an exception but works afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

provided you have access , wouldn't a crossdomain policy file solve the problem?

Comment: hi, there is a crossdomain.xml file like that :
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>